# Extracting words from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a text file, and I want to extract certain words. I would want to extract:

```
Astrid et al. 1980
Bertrand & Calbert 1985
Dilbert et al. 1990
Egbert, Fluff & Gilbert 2000
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
f=open("filename.txt", "r")

words = []
intergers  =[]
for line in f:
    # # print lines
    print(line)

    # splitted words
    words.append(line.split())
    # print(words)

    intergers = line.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0]
```

The text file contains the following:

```
In the beginning Astrid et al. (1980) claimed that the world was flat. 
Bertrand & Calbert (1985) regarded the world as pear-shaped (though it 
wasnâ€™t really) and it was also claimed that the world was oval (Dilbert
et al. 1990). It is now known, however, that the world is square,
following the work of Egbert, Fluff & Gilbert (2000).
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. What should the output be?

Comment: The output should be: ```Astrid et al. 1980
Bertrand & Calbert 1985
Dilbert et al. 1990
Egbert, Fluff & Gilbert 2000```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this solution; it should work in this case since there are only limited ways to cite. If you want something more generalised then the code will get complex and go into the domain of NLP.

```
f = open("filename.txt", "r")

cite_author = []
cite_years = []

for line in f:
    # Removing unnecessary chars, 
    # adding a space afterwards so "." does not interfere
    line = line.replace("(", " ")
    line = line.replace(")", " ")
    
    words = line.split()

    # Going through the entire file
    for count, word in enumerate(words):
        # Only chekcing for author if there is a number
        if word.isnumeric():
            # In case of et al. authors
            if words[count-1] == "al.":
                author = " ".join(words[count-3: count])
                cite_author.append(author)
                # Year is taken only if the author is found, 
                # else it is not appended into list
                cite_years.append(word)
            # In case of A, B, & C (or) A & B authors
            elif words[count-2] == "&":
                if "," in words[count-4]:
                    author = " ".join(words[count-4: count])
                else:
                    author = " ".join(words[count-3: count])
                cite_author.append(author)
                # Year is taken only if the author is found,
                # else it is not appended into list
                cite_years.append(word)

    print(cite_author, cite_years)
```

Output:
[image: Output]

You can check the repl here: https://replit.com/@veedata/AssuredViolentSynergy

Comment: I tried using the method you used but am getting empty arrays

Comment: @humblefool_9 it works for me, I am adding a screenshot for my output, can you check again?

Comment: can you perhaps give me your email ?

Comment: Hey, I hope you were able to solve the problem. Could you also let me know why you would like my email?

Comment: I finally managed, just tweaked few lines of your code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into regular expressions, which you can read about [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). To get you started, here is an example of how to extract, for example, the et al. citations. You can try to find a regular expression that meets all your requirements or use separate ones.

```py
text = "In the beginning Astrid et al. (1980) claimed that the world was flat. Bertrand & Calbert (1985) regarded the world as pear-shaped (though it"

et_als = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]* et al\.\s{1}\(\d{4}\)', text)
print(et_als)
```

The regular expression (`[a-zA-Z]* et al\.\s{1}\(\d{4}\)`), which definitely can be improved, does the following in reversed order:

- You look for years, which are included in brackets, using `\(\d{4}\)`, which means you want 4 digits (i.e, `\d{4}`) in brackets, which need to be escaped (i.e., `\(` and `\)`).
- Before that you have one whitespace (i.e., `\s{1}`)
- Before that you have your et al., whereby the `.` needs to be escaped as well (i.e., `\.`), because it is a special character as the brackets we saw before.
- Last, you know in an et al. you have only one name, which you can get with [a-zA-Z]*, that is, it contains any number of characters (i.e., `*`).

I hope that helps you to get in the right direction.

Comment: regex is hard, and now ended up with two problems to solve

Comment: @humblefool_9 I know the saying and it is true for the first time using regex, however, it is true for everything new you try to understand. Nevertheless, as shown above, regular expressions must not be complicated, but can be kept simple and somehow *readable*, plus they are handy for complicated tasks (e.g., like yours). It frees you from splitting words by spaces and having multiple if conditions on lists to get what you want. Makes the code cleaner in the end. Furthermore, using patterns in a list and using a loop allows you to extend captured citations without adding just another loop.